# Write program that generates 5 random numbers and finds the standard deviation

Tags: python

I am having trouble writing code to generate 5 random integers and finding st. dev. The 5 random int part is done but the st. dev part is incorrect.

```
import random
import math

ranList = []

for x in range(0, 5):
    n = random.randint(1, 10)
    ranList.append(n)

print("Here is the list of 5 random numbers:")
print(ranList)
print("The standard deviation is: ")

def stDev(ranList):      
    ranList = ranList.copy() 
    xbar = sum(ranList)/len(ranList)
    for i in range(len(ranList)):
        ranList[i] -=  xbar
        ranList[i] *= ranList[i]
    s = sum(ranList)
    s /= len(ranList)-1
    return math.sqrt(s)

print(stDev(ranList))
```

Comment: What do you mean "messing up"?

Comment: What output are you expecting, and what are you actually getting? Also, what debugging have you attempted, and where have you narrowed the problem down to?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you do not need a semicolon at the end of each line.

Comment: The output should be the standard deviation of the 5 random numbers. Ignore the "messing up" part, that was poorly worded, I just didnt write functioning code.

Comment: You define a function `stDev` but never seem to call it. Also, probably don't call your private variable `list` (it clashes with a crucial built-in type).

Comment: Thanks for the advice! The function itself doesn't seem to work even if I call it.

Comment: If you're going to do a lot of numeric processing, you might consider switching to NumPy; here's their page for standard deviation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use spyder as this is for my class

Comment: You are trying to divide by a list?  `s /= [sum(list)-1]`

Comment: My variable is called list which may be confusing!

Comment: No, the right side of that division is a list, indicated by the `[]`. We'll need to see a [mcve] though. Incomplete code without a clear description of your problem is unlikely to yield answers.

Comment: @WilliamLasry It's more than confusing - it'll mean that you won't have access to the `list` builtin if you need it. Call it something else. Get rid of the square brackets in the denominator. Actually call your function. Get rid of the redundant semicolons. And then your code is fine. [EDIT: I spoke too soon - the answer is very different from `statistics.stdev` output.]

Comment: I think I figured it out! Thanks everyone

Comment: @WilliamLasry Can you interpret these lines: `ranList[i] -=  xbar`,
        `ranList[i] *= ranList[i]` and `s /= sum(ranList)-1` . please update your post by leaving the comments so that we understand what you are going to implement.

Comment: Yes you've got another problem, you need to `return math.sqrt(s)` . Just invoking `math.sqrt(s)` will not change it to the square root - it will calculate the square root and then discard it.

Comment: I updated it, but the st. dev calculation still seems to be wrong

Comment: And `s /= sum(ranList)-1` is wrong as well. Should be `s /= len(ranList)-1`. After all this, the code is correct.

Comment: One final comment though.  It is not really expected that a function which calculates the standard deviation will also modify the list.  Inside your `stDev` function, start by doing `ranList = ranList.copy()`, and then there will not be any strange surprises inside the calling code.

Comment: Honestly, looks like simple homework but it's kind of challenging without built-in function. You just need to implement Std math formula after you calculate the average. should be just used list or array is also possible?

Comment: I made the edits you suggested but st dev still isn't calculating properly.

Comment: @WilliamLasry If you calculate `statistics.stdev(ranList)` **before** you call your `stDev` you will see that the results agree. See what I mean in my "final" comment above, about not modifying the list? You are probably comparing the result with running `statistics.stdev(ranList)` after you have already called your `stDev` and it has had the side-effect of modifying the list. Hence the suggestion that you should work with a copy instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `statistics` module provided by python like so:

```
import statistics 
import random

# creating sample data 
lst = []
for x in range(0, 5):
   n = random.randint(1, 10)
   lst.append(n) # also don't add semicolons after lines of code, that's not proper formatting

# Prints standard deviation 
print("Standard Deviation of sample is:", statistics.stdev(lst))
```

If you're trying to not use the built in function, try:

```
# Find the mean
total = 0
for num in lst:
   total += num

mean = total/len(lst)

# Subtract mean from each value and square
new_lst = []
new_sum = 0
for item in lst:
   square_diff = (item - mean)**2
   new_lst.append(square_diff)

# Find the average of all the values 
new_lst_sum = 0
for item in new_lst:
    new_lst_sum += item

# print results
standard_dev = float(new_lst_sum/len(new_lst))
print("Your standard deviation is:", standard_dev)
```

This is more code heavy and less productive but you can see the logic clearly.

Comment: I have to do it without built in functions like statistics

Comment: Hope the edited code helps

Comment: @Max This is a different formulation of standard deviation (dividing by `len(new_lst)` rather than `len(new_lst) - 1`) - it is the sample standard deviation rather than the estimator of the population standard deviation. Not wrong, but it is important to be clear about the distinction.

Answer (score 1):

The bug in your latest version of your code is that `s /= len(ranList)-1` should be `s /= len(ranList)`. A couple of things to consider. First, instead of randomly generating lists for your test, use a hard coded list so that its easy to verify. Second, consider making a second internal list in the function so that you don't destroy the list that was passed in.

A solution is

```
import math

def stDev(lst):
    xbar = sum(lst)/len(lst)
    mlst = [(v-xbar)**2 for v in lst]
    s = sum(mlst)/len(mlst)
    return math.sqrt(s)

test = [1, 7, 4, 1, 10]
result = stDev(test)
print(test, result)
```

Comment: This answer matches with the last comment of @alaniwi.

Comment: This is it! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Mario - Could be. I was writing up and testing an answer while comments and changes from OP were coming in.

Comment: To say that use of `len(ranList) - 1` rather than `len(ranList)` is a "bug" is putting it a bit strongly. It depends whether or not the intention is to take account of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction

Comment: @alaniwi -  There are a hundred ways to skin a statistical cat (+/- 10).

Answer (score 0):

You should check two specific line in your code. The first is this:

> s /= sum(ranList)-1

In order to calculate the standard deviation, you want to divide the sum by N-1. Instead, you are dividing it by sum-1. Using the function `len(list)`, which returns the length of a list, is advised.

The second is this:

> math.sqrt(s)

The formula for standard deviation requires to return the square root of your variable `s`. Indeed, the function `math.sqrt(float)` returns the root of the argument, but *it doesn't put the end result into the argument*. Thus, you should also assign the returned value into `s`.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback! Please look at my updated code, it's still giving me the wrong st. dev even accounting for your comments.